# IndexError When Processing Downloaded PDF Files

Tags: python, list

I've encountered an issue while automatically downloading .pdf files and subsequently moving them to a specific folder using Python. I've implemented a function to check if the download is completed before proceeding with the file processing. However, sometimes I'm facing an `IndexError: list index out of range` at the last line of my code.

```
def download_wait():
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    while dl_wait and seconds < 100:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        for fname in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Testuser\Downloads"):
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload') or fname.endswith('.tmp'):
                dl_wait = True
        seconds += 1
    return seconds

Years = ["2010", "2011"]
for year in Years:
    try:
        report = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//span[@class='btn_archived download'][.//a[contains(@href,{year})]]")
        if len(report) != 0:
            report[0].click()
            download_wait()
            files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Testuser\Downloads")
            filtered_files = [file for file in files if file.lower().endswith(('.pdf', '.htm'))]
            print(files, year, filtered_files)
            filename = filtered_files[0]  # IndexError occurs here
```

The problem is that the `filtered_files` list is sometimes empty, leading to the IndexError. Even though there is a .pdf file in the Downloads folder, it seems that the list remains empty.

For example, in one attempt the output of `print(files, year, filtered_files)` is before the error occurs:

```
['NYSE_XOM_2009.pdf'] 2009 ['NYSE_XOM_2009.pdf']
['NYSE_XOM_2010.pdf.crdownload'] 2010 []
```

I am wondering why `files` can take on `['NYSE_XOM_2010.pdf.crdownload']`, given that the `download_wait()` should have prevented this to happen.

Any tips what might cause this issue would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Show us the output from `print(files)`.

Comment: Done, see initial post

Answer (score 0):

If there was pdf file is existed in your folder, this code should be worked.
You might confuse because of `print` statement return a result that has pdf file but it's in other loop.

e.g. year 2010 has pdf file, but 2011 hasn't.

I suggest to print `year` and `filtered_files` with `files` like

```
...
files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Testuser\Downloads")
filtered_files = [file for file in files if file.lower().endswith(('.pdf', '.htm'))]
print(files, year, filtered_files)
...
```

Then you will know exact situation inside of loop.

---

updated answer.

check out this line. `['NYSE_XOM_2010.pdf.crdownload'] 2010 []`

first element of list ends with `.pdf.crdownload` not `.pdf`.

nothing is wrong with your code. I don't know what `crdownload` is, but I'm sure is not a pdf file; perhaps a file that is unfinished downloading from chrome browser?

If you'd like to handle a file with `crdownload` extension, you must change your code from `file.lower().endswith(('.pdf', '.htm'))`

to `file.lower().endswith(('.pdf', '.htm', '.crdownload'))` or `file.lower().endswith(('.pdf', '.htm', '.pdf.crdownload'))`

You can check your code snippet in python shell.

```
❯ python
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jul 25 2023, 17:36:13) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "foo.pdf".endswith((".pdf", ".htm"))
True
>>> "foo.pdf.crdownload".endswith((".pdf", ".htm"))
False
>>> "foo.pdf.crdownload".endswith((".pdf", ".htm", ".crdownload"))
True
>>> "foo.pdf.crdownload".endswith((".pdf", ".htm", ".pdf.crdownload"))
True
```